# Can you add dynamic elements inside of another dynamic element on load in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to initialize a div with a text area inside of it on load. I populate the the text area with data still during the load process. Once all elements are created I go out and find the elements and use "appendTo" to add another set of dynamic elements all during the load process.

Here's where the first set of elements load...

```
 j$(function() {

                   for(var i = 0; i < Survey_result.length; i++){

                    j$('<div id="QDiv'+Survey_result[i].Id+'">'+
                          '<div id="'+Survey_result[i].Survey_Question__r.Question_Input_Type__c+'">'+
                             '<textarea cols="130" id="Q_'+Survey_result[i].Survey_Question__c+'"  readonly="true" name="p_Q">'+Survey_result[i].Survey_Question__r.Question__c+'</textarea>'+
                          '</div>'+   
                      '<div>').appendTo('#SurveyBuilder_div');
                      QelId='#Q'+i;
                   }
```

Here is where I try to add the child elements but they aren't loading. Is it because it's not seeing the parent element id?

```
   if(QuestionType=='PickList'){

                               j$('<div id="ADiv'+QId+'">'+
                                  '<select id="selAnswer'+i+'" size="1">'+      
                                  '</select>'+
                                   '</div>').after(MainDiv);
                                   bp='#ADiv'+QId;

                                 j$(Answer_result).each(function(){

                                           j$(' <option value = "'+Answer_result[b].Id+'">'+Answer_result[b].Answer__c+'</option>').after(bp);
                                           b++;
                                 });                   

                        }else if(QuestionType=='Radio'){
                               j$('<div id="ADiv'+QId+'">'+
                                  '</div>').appendTo(MainDiv);

                                   bp='ADiv'+QId;

                                j$(Answer_result).each(function(){
                                       j$('<input type="radio" id="Radio_CtrlType'+b+'" value="'+Answer_result[b].Id+'" name="ctrlSel'+i+'"/>'+
                                          '<label for="Radio_CtrlType'+b+'">'+Answer_result[b].Answer__c+'</label>').appendTo(bp);
                                           b++;
                                 });
                         }else if(QuestionType=='Checkbox'){
                                j$('<div id="ADiv'+QId+'">'+
                                   '</div>').appendTo(MainDiv);
                                    bp='ADiv'+QId;

                                j$(Answer_result).each(function(){
                                      j$('<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox_CtrlType'+b+'" value="'+Answer_result[b].Id+'" name="ctrlSel'+i+'"/>'+
                                         '<label for="Checkbox_CtrlType'+b+'">'+Answer_result[b].Answer__c+'</label>').appendTo(bp);
                                         b++;
                                }); 
                         }else if(QuestionType=='Textbox'){
                              j$('<div id="ADiv'+QId+'">'+
                                 '</div>').appendTo(MainDiv);
                               bp='ADiv'+QId;
                               j$(Answer_result).each(function(){
                                     j$('<input type="text" id="Textbox_CtrlType'+b+'" value="'+Answer_result[b].Id+'" name="ctrlSel'+i+'"/>').appendTo(bp); 
                                    b++;
                               });
                         }
```

Comment: Is the original 'dynamic' content being loaded asynchronously with ajax? Or just generated at load-time with the JS?

Comment: Generated at load time with js

Comment: are you certain the 2nd set of code runs after the first?

Comment: Yep. Added an alert in the Survey_result for loop and the .each function. The Survey_result returned all values in the alert box then the .each function returned all the data it was supposed to be displaying. The order of the code i displayed is how it looks in my script blocks.

Comment: Here's the [code...](http://i.imgur.com/WwuEm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When modifying content on a page, you need to

1) make sure the page is already loaded (don't do anything until after domready, which you are doing correctly, and

2) If you still don't see your content, most likely your target element selector is returning nothing.  To check this, do a `console.log($('#yourselector').length);`If length is 0, it's not finding anything on the page to add to.

(btw, `console.log();`  logs to the developer console, such as is available in all major browsers these days)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about using the .length for debug. Got it working!